# How do you get the previous command in Clozure?

Tags: macos, common-lisp, ccl

I'm using the Common Lisp Clozure environment on the Mac.  What is the key shortcut to get the previous commands entered in the REPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key shortcut to get the previous commands entered in the listener of CCL:

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>